# Почему код в этом блоке повторяется столько раз сколько ты оправляешь картинок боту? Как это исправить?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=Registration.Q9)
async def tower(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    photos = message.photo
    await photos[-1].download(destination_file=f'./img/{message.from_user.id}/{photos[-1].file_id}.jpg')
    file_ids = photos[-1].file_id
    await state.update_data(file_ids=file_ids)
    print('It is ok')
    await Registration.next()
```